# Use of "which" directly after a word that it is not pointing to

Tags: grammaticality

My question is about the following sentence:

> We have created a system to support operations of the devices, which processes and sends out data.

Would you say this use of "which" is OK? I'm not sure because the "which" comes directly after the word "devices" which it is not pointing to, instead the "which" is pointing to "system". I wondered if there was some kind of rule about that.

Comment: I don't think it's problematic. If you're worried about ambiguity, though, you could write, "We have created a system, which processes and sends out data, to support operations of the devices."

Comment: It is fine. The relativised element 'which' has the noun phrase 'a system to support operations of the devices' as antecedent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's okay, the singular verb following which implies that a singular noun is referenced. This noun-job is taken up by the [noun phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase), *a system to support operations of the devices.*

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is grammatical because the singular verbs (*processes* and *sends*) make the antecedent of *which* the singular noun (*system*) and not the nearby plural noun (*devices*). But it's problematic because it presents what some call a garden path -- a misleading alternate parse that may confuse readers. This arises because English allows the repetition of an antecedent, and *processes* is also a plural noun. Consider the following sentence:

> We have created a system of **processes** to support the operation of the devices, which **processes** send out data.

Such a parse in the original sentence is unsupportable once a reader reaches *sends*, but it is considered bad form to put such a stumbling block in the reader's way.

Comment: Another driveby downvoter, a plague upon this site, delivers another discourtesy to author and readers alike.